Rounding vertices of polygon to fixed number of decimal places in QGIS
When I digitize a polygon and snap to existing features, sometimes the coordinates end up very slightly away from where I want them to be for example 15.000000099, rather than 16.
Is there a way to round each vertex to a fixed precision?

Are you talking about manually editing those features?

No. I want some way to run a rounding function across all vertices, then save the rounded geometry without manually editing.

Then you'd probably have to extract vertices, round those $x and $y values by updating the geometry using the field calculator, convert them to lines and the lines to polygons. Or do something very convoluted using pyhton and point_n in order to edit the geometry of each vertex of each polygon.

Perhaps there is a mistake here (should be 15): for example 15.000000099, rather than 16.

Try Snap points to grid

Why would you want to snap double precision rounding of a value near 15 to 16?

It sounds odd but here is the context. It is a permit application to cover an area adjoining an existing permit. If it overlaps even by a tiny amount then it gives grounds for rejection.

Please [Edit] the Question to provide clarity in response to requests for clarification.

THIS WILL OVERWRITE YOUR DATA (MAKE A COPY)
That's easy:

Open Field Calculator.
Insert this code: geom_from_wkt(geom_to_wkt(@geometry, 0))
Replace 0 with precision you need.
Check box Update existing field.
Choose <geometry>as a field.
Press OK.




-parameters ---->before ------->after
Another example with point:

P.S. This can collapse your polygons to a point or line, so choose precision wisely.

Okay, that's way easier than I thought it would be =D

Great answer -didn't know about the possibility to update geometries with field calculator! Do you know since which version this is possible?

@Babel This feature was implemented in 2016. Changelog for QGIS 2.14 2016-02-26: https://www.qgis.org/project/visual-changelogs/visualchangelog214/#feature-field-calculator-can-be-used-to-update-features-geometry

Thanks for this. I will revert and accept once I have tested it.

You can use the "Snap points to grid" (native:snappointstogrid) processing algorithm https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-points-to-grid

As with all ways to do this in QGIS at the moment, this can lead to invalid geometries. If you want to have this solved, please "vote" on this QGIS issue :-): https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/58023

I will try this. However, the polygons were digitised by snapping to a generated grid of points at regular spacing, so I was surprised to find that some of the vertices were not exact when I extracted them. That is what I am trying to remedy.

@LeighBettenay, I didn't understand correctly your question. May you please better clarify the issue?
